# how to access object property in this case

Tags: html, ios, oop, xcode5, uitableview

project type: masterview application
 components first view: Tableview 
 second view :webview
 what i want is to navigate in such a technique that : when user taps a cell, it should get the `href` property and to open in next webview, the page it links to.. instead of only `href` property

suggestion 
 thanks

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "TFHpple.h"
#import "TFHppleElement.h"




#import "Preface.h"
#import "Chapters.h"
#import "Index.h"



#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * preface;
    NSMutableArray * chapters;
    NSMutableArray * index;
}

@end


@implementation MasterViewController
```

```
- (void) loadChapters
{

    ///// capturing the link /////
    /*
     NSURL pointer to store the file url
     */

    NSURL * chapter_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test/mainpage" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];


    NSData * chapter_data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:chapter_url];


    ///// passing to TFHpple /////


    TFHpple * chapter_parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:chapter_data];



    ///// String for XPath Query /////

    NSString * chapter_query_string = @"//div[@class='cD']/ul[2]/li/a";
    NSArray * chapter_nodes = [chapter_parser searchWithXPathQuery:chapter_query_string];

    ///// Array for initializing elements of preface/////

    NSMutableArray * chapter_contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

    ///// Now  looping to fetch contents /////

    for (TFHppleElement * element in chapter_nodes) {

        Chapters * chapter_ptr =[[Chapters alloc]init];

        [chapter_contents addObject:chapter_ptr];

        chapter_ptr.chapter_title = [[element firstChild]content];

        chapter_ptr.chapter_url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];


    }

    chapters= chapter_contents;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

**viewdidload**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadPreface];
    [self loadChapters]; 
    [self loadIndex];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   }
```

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return @"Table of Contents";
            break;
        case 1:
            return @"Chapters";
            break;
        case 3:
            return @"Index";
            break;


    }
    return nil;
}
```

**Method returning no of rows in a section**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return preface.count;
            break;
        case 1:
            return chapters.count;
            break;
        case 2:
            return index.count;
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

     switch (indexPath.section) {
case 0:
    {

        Preface *preface_access = [preface objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = preface_access.preface_title;
        return cell;
    }
case 1:
    {
        Chapters * chapter_access = [chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = chapter_access.chapter_title;
        return cell;


    }

    case 2:
   {
        Index * index_access = [index objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = index_access.index_title;
       return cell;
   }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
```

**i want to do something like this** 
in **detailviewcontroller.m**
it is the 2nd view controller

this is pseudo code I am weak in OOP concepts so appologies

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray * contentsfromprevious = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

    Preface * data = [[Preface alloc]init];
    data.preface_url = contentsfromprevious;


    data = preface_contents;
    [self.loadwebview.request];
    }
```

Comment: the difference between raywenderlich and mine application he is doing online parsing and i am doing offline..

Comment: "I have a case where i am showing the code" except you're not showing any code. WHich is probably why you got downvoted.

Comment: i tried to post on this but it did not worked so 
 i left a refrence of my task.
[http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios]

Comment: you need to show us YOUR code. We know that the Ray's code works.

Comment: Unless your code is absolutely identical to that of ray wenderlich then I doubt anybody is going to spend the time looking through that then trying to figure out where that differs from what you have done if you can't post your code, most people simply don't have the time.

Comment: this is exactly the same practice i required but after that i am stucked how to the url to next view and to load that page in uiwebview

Comment: @JohnGreen please review this

Comment: @MartinH can you please check out

Comment: what exactly is the problem that your facing.

Comment: i am unable to swith on to the second view controller
I have posted the 2nd view controller's 'viewdidload' method, if happens it should get the url and find in the local directory named test and open the webpage

Comment: your problem is not clear. Please be specific about what your need is.

Comment: @Shabib please check out i have made my stetement more clear to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your question is still not clear enough. What I've come to understand that, you want something like this:

1. In the MasterViewController you wish show a list of your links (html pages stored locally).
2. If any of the table view cells are tapped, you want to display the locally stored html page in a web view on the DetailViewController.

Assuming this, you should implement this UITableViewDelegate method on your MasterViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailVC.htmlFileName = [htmlFiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // you might need to change this according to your need, as I said your requirement is unclear
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: detailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Also you'll need to add this into your `DetailViewController.h` file

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *htmlFileName;
```

And after you've done this, you should change your DetailViewControllers viewDidLoad method into something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // your code
    // ....

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: htmlFileName ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];

    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    // your code
    // ...
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you really want though. On the other note, you don't have to put `break` statements after any `return` statements. It never gets executed.

Comment: i am getting error in the viewDidLoad method. What is webView undeclared identifier what should i do??

Comment: can you please explain some to me, how it is working.. if you have any question regarding this project you may ask i will provide it...

Comment: webView is the UIWebView where you want to display your html content. Declare it on .h file (make an IBOutlet, if you prefer or you can allocate it and initialise it in the view did load method before using it).